# Transaction is getting reverted in the `refundToInsurer()` function call

Tags: solidity, etherscan, brownie, transfer, goerli

The deployment of `InsuranceProvider` is working fine and the calling of `newContract()` with the required parameters is successfully creating/deploying the `InsuranceConsumer` contract. Even, the `payOutContract()` is working correctly in terms of transferring the ETH balance from the `InsuranceConsumer` to the **client's** wallet.

The issue is with the `refundToInsurer()` function, as it's expected to transfer the ETH balance from the `InsuranceConsumer` to the **insurer's** wallet, but it's transaction is getting failed/reverted.

Here's the code:

```
SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract InsuranceProvider {
    address payable public insurer;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(insurer == msg.sender, "Only Insurance provider can do this");
        _;
    }

    constructor() payable {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e
        );
        insurer = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function newContract(
        address payable _client,
        uint256 _premium,
        uint256 _payoutValue
    ) public payable onlyOwner returns (address) {
        //create contract, send payout amount so contract is fully funded plus a small buffer
        InsuranceConsumer i = (new InsuranceConsumer){
            value: ((_payoutValue * 1 ether) / (uint256(getLatestPrice())))
        }(_client, _premium, _payoutValue);

        return address(i);
    }

    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int256) {
        (, int256 price, , uint256 timeStamp, ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // If the round is not complete yet, timestamp is 0
        require(timeStamp > 0, "Round not complete");
        return price;
    }

    function payOutContract(address _contract) public {
        InsuranceConsumer i = InsuranceConsumer(_contract);
        // Transfer agreed amount to client
        i.payOutContract();
    }

    function refundToInsurer(address _contract) public onlyOwner  {
        InsuranceConsumer i = InsuranceConsumer(_contract);
        // Transfer back the amount to insurer 
        i.refundToInsurer();
   }
}

contract InsuranceConsumer {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
    address payable public insurer;
    address payable client;
    uint256 startDate;
    uint256 premium;
    uint256 payoutValue;

    constructor(
        address payable _client,
        uint256 _premium,
        uint256 _payoutValue
    ) payable {
        //set ETH/USD Price Feed
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e
        );

        //first ensure insurer has fully funded the contract
        require(
            msg.value >= _payoutValue / uint256(getLatestPrice()),
            "Not enough funds sent to contract"
        );

        //now initialize values for the contract
        insurer = payable(msg.sender);
        client = _client;
        startDate = block.timestamp; //contract will be effective immediately on creation
        premium = _premium;
        payoutValue = _payoutValue;
    }

    function payOutContract() public {
        //Transfer agreed amount to client
        client.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function refundToInsurer() public {
        // Transfer back the amount to insurer
        insurer.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int256) {
        (, int256 price, , uint256 timeStamp, ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // If the round is not complete yet, timestamp is 0
        require(timeStamp > 0, "Round not complete");
        return price;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help by pointing out the logical mistake that I'm doing in the `refundToInsurer()` function ?

Comment: is there any possibility the insurer is a contract address which blocked receiving ETH?

Comment: @AllenWong, the insurer and client are wallets and the InsuranceProvider and InsuranceConsumer are the contracts, both of these contracts are declared as payable. 

The `payOutContract()` function is getting called and completed perfectly. But, the problem is in the case of `refundToInsurer()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, we're creating the `InsuranceConsumer` using the `newContract()` function of `InsuranceProvider`. Therefore, the `msg.sender` of the `InsuranceConsumer` is going to be the `InsuranceProvider` itself, not the **insurer's** wallet.

So, when we're calling the `refundInsurer()` of `InsuranceConsumer` via `InsuranceProvider`, then it's doing:

```
insurer.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

It means to transfer the available ETH in the `InsuranceConsumer` to the `InsuranceProvider` (not the insurer's wallet), and since `InsuranceProvider` is not expected to be a `receiver`, that's why it's reverting the transaction.

So, the corrected code will be:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract InsuranceProvider {
    address payable public insurer;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(insurer == msg.sender, "Only Insurance provider can do this");
        _;
    }

    constructor() payable {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e
        );
        insurer = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function newContract(
        address payable _client,
        uint256 _premium,
        uint256 _payoutValue
    ) public payable onlyOwner returns (address) {
        //create contract, send payout amount so contract is fully funded plus a small buffer
        InsuranceConsumer i = (new InsuranceConsumer){
            value: ((_payoutValue * 1 ether) / (uint256(getLatestPrice())))
        }(_client, _premium, _payoutValue);

        return address(i);
    }

    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int256) {
        (, int256 price, , uint256 timeStamp, ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // If the round is not complete yet, timestamp is 0
        require(timeStamp > 0, "Round not complete");
        return price;
    }

    function payOutContract(address _contract) public onlyOwner {
        // Transfer agreed amount to client
        InsuranceConsumer i = InsuranceConsumer(_contract);
        i.payOutContract();
    }

    function refundToInsurer(address _contract) public onlyOwner {
        // Transfer back the amount to insurer 
        InsuranceConsumer i = InsuranceConsumer(_contract);
        i.refundToInsurer(insurer);
   }
}

contract InsuranceConsumer {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
    address payable public insurer;
    address payable client;
    uint256 startDate;
    uint256 premium;
    uint256 payoutValue;

    constructor(
        address payable _client,
        uint256 _premium,
        uint256 _payoutValue
    ) payable {
        //set ETH/USD Price Feed
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e
        );

        //first ensure insurer has fully funded the contract
        require(
            msg.value >= _payoutValue / uint256(getLatestPrice()),
            "Not enough funds sent to contract"
        );

        //now initialize values for the contract
        insurer = payable(msg.sender);
        client = _client;
        startDate = block.timestamp; //contract will be effective immediately on creation
        premium = _premium;
        payoutValue = _payoutValue;
    }

    function payOutContract() public {
        //Transfer agreed amount to client
        client.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function refundToInsurer(address payable _insurer) public {
        // Transfer back the amount to insurer 
        _insurer.transfer(address(this).balance);
   }

    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int256) {
        (, int256 price, , uint256 timeStamp, ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // If the round is not complete yet, timestamp is 0
        require(timeStamp > 0, "Round not complete");
        return price;
    }
}
```

Now, while calling the `refundInsurer()`, we're explicitly passing the insurer as the parameter, and it's taking the value of `msg.sender` from `InsuranceProvider`, so the `msg.sender` is going to be the **insurer's** wallet (with which the `InsuranceProvider` is being deployed) in this case.

And now, when we're calling the `refundInsurer()` of `InsuranceConsumer` via `InsuranceProvider`, then it's doing:

```
_insurer.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

It means to transfer the available ETH in the `InsuranceConsumer` to the **insurer's** wallet. So, the transaction will be successful resulting in the withdrawal of the funds from the `InsuranceConsumer` to the **insurer's** wallet.